# How to convert a value to a string?

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

I am attempting to print a value which is not a string to the console.

In this case it is an array of integers.

How can I convert an array or any other value which allows such behaviour to a string.

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console
import Data.Array


main = log [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When I run the above the compiler gives the following error:

```
Could not match type

  Array Int

  with type

  String


while checking that type Array t0 is at least as general

as type String while checking that expression

  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

has type String in value declaration main

where t0 is an unknown type
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're trying to use `logShow` and not `log`?

Comment: I don't think there is an instance of `Show` for `Array` by default. Oops, in fact there is. I just tried online and it compiled.

Comment: @RegisKuckaertz yes, there is. Try it for yourself: the program above compiles and runs. Plus, even if there was no instance, the error message would have been different: it would have said something like "no instance `Show (Array Int)` blah-blah-blah".

Comment: Yeah just tested. Thanks!

Comment: Correct the original intention was to use log. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly how you should convert an array to a string depends on what you need to do with that string. That is, it depends on who is going to consume that string and how. The possibilities range from just turning it into a string "array" all the way to binary-base64-encoding.

If all you need is just print it out for debugging or educational purposes, then use the [function `show` from type class `Show`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/3.1.0/docs/Data.Show#v:show). There is an instance of that type class defined for arrays, so the function will work in your case.

```
main = log $ show [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If you want to take a shortcut, use the function `logShow`, which does literally the above:

```
main = logShow [1,2,3,4,5]
```

An alternative way to print out stuff for debugging purposes is [the `traceAny` function from `Debug.Trace`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-debug/3.0.0/docs/Debug.Trace#v:traceAny). This function doesn't require a `Show` instance, because it uses the native JavaScript `console.log`, which will just dump the raw JSON representation of your value:

```
main = traceAny [1,2,3,4,5] \_ -> pure unit
```

Beware though: this function is for debugging only, do not use it for reliable output.